# Can I do RegAsm of .Net2 dll with .Net4 RegAsm.exe?

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, registry, regasm

Can I do RegAsm to a .NET 2 dll with .Net4 RegAsm.exe?
I have only .NET 4 installed on my machine and I need to do RegAsm to a .NET 2 file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can. The RuntimeVersion value written to the registry will be set according to the CLR header (that is, even if you register the 2.0 DLL with 4.0 RegAsm, it will 'know' that it's a 2.0 DLL and register it accordingly).

Comment: Thanks alot! can you show me some msdn or another article? it will be great

Comment: The official reference - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tzat5yw6.aspx - does not mention this behavior, but you can decompile `System.Runtime.InteropServices.RegistrationServices.RegisterAssembly` and the relevant line - `string imageRuntimeVersion = assembly.ImageRuntimeVersion;` - is there.