# CoCreateInstance error 0x80131700 in Windows 10: unable to work with .NET runtime 4.0

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, com, .net-framework-version

I have a legacy 32 bit application running in Windows 10 Enterprise version 20H2 Build 19042.1052 with .NET Framework 4.8 Advanced Series pre-installed in the operating system and active.

The legacy application loads a .NET assembly written in C# and built for x86 with target framework .NET 2.0 through the following C++ code as a COM object:

```
    #import "myassembly.tlb" no_namespace, raw_interfaces_only

    IMyClass *pMyClass = nullptr;
```

...

```
    HRESULT hr;
    CLSID clsid;

    // Load myassembly.dll as a COM object
    CoInitializeEx(nullptr, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);
    CLSIDFromString(OLESTR("{c0dc113c-3839-4427-8da5-35d768aff3d6}"), &clsid);          // This is the uuid of MyClass in myassembly.tlh
    hr = CoCreateInstance(clsid, nullptr, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, __uuidof(IMyClass), reinterpret_cast<LPVOID *>(&pMyClass));
    if (FAILED(hr) || pMyClass == nullptr)
    {
        cout << "Cannot create COM Object\n";
        cout << "CoCreateInstance" << " hr = 0x" << std::hex << hr << " - ";
        std::wcout << getErrMsg(hr);
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;
    }
```

I don't want to install the .NET framework 3.5 on Windows 10, so I added a .config file for the .NET assembly and for all its .NET dependencies like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
  <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
  <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>
</startup>
</configuration>
```

I tried with or without the `useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true"` option, but invariably I get an error 0x80131700 ("Unknown error") and a window pops up asking to start installation of .NET Framework 3.5, which I don't want to do, as said. Indeed, if I install it, everything is working fine.

Any hint?

Comment: Error is CLR_E_SHIM_RUNTIMELOAD https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/deployment/initialization-errors-managing-the-user-experience. You say you've added a ".config file for the .NET assembly", but you must use an app.config file (myprogram.exe.config file aside myprogram.exe)

Comment: @Simon Mourier that's what I did for the .dll, I did that also for the .exe, but in this case it is not actually applicable for the .exe, because it is not .NET.

Comment: Of course it's applicable. It's useless for the .dll

Comment: So what is the purpose of *.dll.config files and why does Visual Studio produce them?

Comment: @Simon Mourier, you are right, it's working now, thank you.

Comment: @BillyJoe I have a question for my own edification and maybe those who might read later... How did you register the .NET assembly for COM? Did you use the v4/x86 regasm.exe to do it, or are you using isolated COM?

Comment: @JosephWillcoxson yes I used the v4.0 regasm:  ```regasm.exe myassembly.dll /tlb: myassembly.tlb /codebase```. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10878357/7231208) the regasm version is not important.

Comment: @BillyJoe Thanks. Interesting. I remember having problems when not using the right version of regasm and having problems--and I think it was version and not just bitness. Nice that it works.

Comment: @JosephWillcoxson regasm has a "regfile" option to save a text file with all the changes that would be done to the registry, without actually doing them. If you compare the two generated files with regasm 2.0 and regasm 4.0 starting from the same .dll .NET 2.0, you will find them identical. I just tried that today.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments by @Simon Mourier, the problem was I needed to add a .config file like the one in the question for the executable (myexe.exe.config) rather than for the .NET assembly (myassembly.dll.config). The latter one is actually useless.